# Retrieve Facebook User Profile After Authorizing Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Currently, I have something setup similar to this tutorial (http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

At the moment, I can retrieve users' information right after they have authorized the application and it outputs something like this.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123456
    [name] => First Last
    [first_name] => Firstname
    [last_name] => Lastname
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/username
    [username] => username
    [birthday] => 01/01/1901
)
```

Is it possible to pull information from users that already accepted the application?

Comment: What do you mean from information? If you mean their basic info, here's a similar question that answers it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900137/retrieving-user-information-from-facebook

Comment: @parioscreations, I'm talking about information from the opengraph, and I posted an example output above. If an app that has been created has 100 users who authorized it, is there a way to retrive their profile information, such as their name, etc and insert it into a database.

Comment: I believe so... Are you asking for the code that enables you to save the user's info into a database?

Comment: @parioscreations, no. Inputting into a database isn't the issue. It's retrieving the information as I've stated.

Comment: I understand your question now! Sorry, I'm a bit blind. :P

Comment: Please tell me, as I cannot understand this, what language are you writing your application in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comments, I am presuming that the question can be rephrased this way "100 users authorized my app, now I want to retrive basic information about all of them. Does facebook give a way for me to go and fetch the list of all such users and their basic information?" If this the question, the answer is no, you can't.

When the user authorizes the app, you would have received an access_token which you must retain along with their fbId and other information before processing the user. If you only want basic information, process the data when the user authorizes your app and store it. If you don't, you are not guaranteed to get a chance again.

If you have not processed the data so far, your best option is to wait for user to come back to your app and provide you with a fresh access_token which you can use to get the information by accessing the URL - "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx".

Hope this answers your question.